# solving the limit of $(e^{2x}+x)^{1/x}$

Tags: limits

I tried to solve for the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} (e^{2x}+x)^{1/x}$$
and I reached to the indeterminate form: 
$${4e^{2x}}\over {4e^{2x}}$$ 
if I plug in, I will get another indeterminate form!

Comment: Isn't that leave you a $1$ in the indeterminate form you got?

Comment: But the limit is at least $\lim e^{{2x}({1\over x})}$ which is $e^2$, so the indeterminate form must be wrong.

Comment: Looking at the solutions below I am thinking why none of them came to my mind? :) learned a lot. :)

Answer (score 5):

Tricky solution:
$$\begin{align}
(e^{2x}+x)^{1/x}&=e^{2x/x}\left(1+\frac{1}{e^{2x}/x}\right)^{1/x}\\
&=e^2\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{e^{2x}/x}\right)^{e^{2x}/x}\right)^{e^{-2x}}
\end{align}$$

Since $e^{2x}/x\to\infty$ and $(1+1/y)^y\to e$ as $y\to\infty$, and $e^{-2x}\to 0$, you get the limit is $e^2$.

Comment: We don't need the last step, from here $$ e^{2x/x}\left(1+\frac{1}{e^{2x}/x}\right)^{1/x} \to e^2\cdot 1^0 =e^2$$

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how you got $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{4e^{2x}}{4e^{2x}}$, but as has been pointed out, that limit is easily evaluated: the fraction is identically $1$, so the limit is also $1$.

Let $L=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(e^{2x}+x\right)^{1/x}$; then

$$\ln L=\ln\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(e^{2x}+x\right)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(e^{2x}+x\right)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(e^{2x}+x\right)}x\;.$$

Now apply l’Hospital’s rule.

Comment: Limits aren't indeterminate. The exist or not. Indeterminate means the form. And OP said "indeterminate form," anyway.

Comment: Now your just being sad. :)

Comment: It's the "why" for your pedantic correctness that is sad. Look into your heart, Luke, you know it is true.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, I'm sure. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way, considering $$A=(e^{2x}+x)^{1/x}$$ Taking logarithms $$\log(A)=\frac 1x \log(e^{2x}+x)=\frac 1x \left(\log(e^{2x})+\log(1+\frac x {e^{2x}})\right)=\frac 1x \left(2x+\log(1+\frac x {e^{2x}})\right)$$ $$\log(A)=2+\frac 1x \log(1+\frac x {e^{2x}})\approx 2+\frac 1x \frac x {e^{2x}}=2+\frac 1 {e^{2x}}$$

Comment: so two limits comes up in two answers, both are true? i've also got your result though.

Comment: The limit is $\log(A)=2$ that is to say $A=e^2$

Comment: oh yes my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$x>0\implies e^x>x \implies e^2=(e^{2 x})^{1/x}<(e^{2x}+x)^{1/x}<    (2 e^{2x})^{1/x}    =(e^2) (2^{1/x})$..... And $\lim_{x\to \infty}2^{1/x}=1.$

Answer (score 0):

We simply have

$$(e^{2x}+x)^{1/x}=e^{2x/x}\left(1+\frac{x}{e^{2x}}\right)^{1/x}\to e^2\cdot1^0=e^2$$